# How to use the timezone function in ruby's stdlib?

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

The [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+New+Time+Instance) state that I can pass a `timezone` to the Time initializer:

```rb
zone = timezone("Europe/Athens")      # Eastern European Time, UTC+2
Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2, zone) #=> 2002-10-31 02:02:02 +0200
```

However, when I try calling `timezone` I get `undefined method 'timezone'`. Is there a particular require that I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `timezone` method you are referring to is actually just an example. It doesn't exist in Ruby. I agree, the wording and example is perhaps a bit misleading.

Ruby stdlib passes around timezones as strings, by either passing a timezone UTC offset or name. This is shown [in the first example](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+New+Time+Instance):

> You can pass a UTC offset:
>
> ```
> Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2, "+02:00") #=> 2002-10-31 02:02:02 +0200
> ```

Note the string `"+02:00"`.

Then the "incriminated" example you are referring to:

> Or a timezone object:
>
> ```
> zone = timezone("Europe/Athens")      # Eastern European Time, UTC+2
> Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2, zone) #=> 2002-10-31 02:02:02 +0200
> ```

The way you should read this example is as if somewhere you have a piece of code, here the hypothetical method `timezone`, that returns an object representing a TZ that can be provided to the initializer.

A practical example is the following one, using the widely adopted [tzinfo](https://rubygems.org/gems/tzinfo/) library:

```
[2] pry(main)> require 'tzinfo'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/New_York>
[4] pry(main)> Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2, tz)
=> 2002-10-31 02:02:02 -0500
[5] pry(main)> Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2)
=> 2002-10-31 02:02:02 +0100
```

Note how in the example above the hypothetical method `timezone` is replaced with the actual code that initializes a new TZ object from `tzinfo`.

Finally, you can access the timezone setting by calling `zone` on the `Time` object. Note that what you get depends on the object you used to initialize the zone. By default it is a string, but if I use `tzinfo` as in the example below, I get the tzinfo instance.

```
[6] pry(main)> Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2, 2, 2, tz).zone
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/New_York>
[7] pry(main)> Time.new.zone
=> "CET"
```

To summarize, there is no `timezone` method defined (which actually the way it is show in the docs would require it to be defined in `Kernel`, which would be even more strange in Ruby). It was just a placeholder example.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the timezone method is undefined. There is a trick though on Unix to convert Time object to any time zone. The timezone("Europe/Athens") is meant to talk to the C library underling the Time class ("zoneinfo" database located in /usr/share/zoneinfo/). So you can temporarily change the "system" time zone for the current process by setting the env variable TZ to an appropriate value.

```
class Time
  def convert_zone(to_zone)
    original_zone = ENV["TZ"]
    utc_time = dup.gmtime
    ENV["TZ"] = to_zone
    to_zone_time = utc_time.localtime
    ENV["TZ"] = original_zone
    return to_zone_time
  end
end

t = Time.now
t.convert_zone("Europe/Athens")
```

This is the equivalent of writing your own timezone method :)

Comment: Your code returns an instance of `Time`, not a timezone that can be passed to `Time.new` as shown in the OP's example.

Comment: In my case, ENV["TZ"] is not set, so perhaps some bit of your infra is configuring that environment variable for you. I understand the approach though, thanks for the trick!

Comment: Yes, that correct if not set ruby refer to /etc/localtime. If TZ is set in ENV that affect how time is displayed (in ~/.bashrc for example), otherwise you can set it directly in the script (ENV["TZ"] = "your_timezone")